# How do I improve a uv mapping (mirrored)?

Tags: uv

I'm a modder and working on a car for a game, but I'm struggling to find a suitable solution for the mapping. The current model  maps both sides of the car on one isle, which means that in the game one of the 2 sides is mirrored.  The results are not acceptable.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

I'm trying to avoid a complete remap, but I seem to be stuck.

Comment: Nope you are not stuck, it's pretty easy to do on blender which is to select the side that needs to be remap and unwrap it and stitch it back to the original UV. Then you may have to replicated the texture map in photoshop or equivalent software.

Comment: No that doesn't really help much. I have something like 5 different lods to do and if I load the entire model with all its lods to do it at once it simply generates 20 more materials and makes it a nightmare. I can't simply cut and stich the actual mesh either, the model is too complex to make it accurately. 

Also why was the entire post edited? It's clearly telling a completely different story to what I originally said.

Comment: Will having 2 Material solve the issue? You could load 2 material and have them on different ID. What game engine are you working with? Reworking it would definitely save some precious resources but if you need something quick and dirty that may be one of the way.